# How to export text data with Hebrew and special characters from SAS to ACCESS?

Tags: ms-access, sas, hebrew

I have a SAS table that contains hundreds of thousands of rows and several text fields and I need to import this table into and ACCESS database.

The fields contains names in Hebrew characters and special characters such as commas, colons, brackets, quotes, double quotes and any other character you can think of.

I've tried exporting the table as a CSV file and importing it into my ACCESS database and encountered 2 issues:

1. Access does not recognize the Hebrew characters
2. Every time there is a special character that is also defined as a delimiter in the access import query, the data is read incorrectly.

Any ideas?

Im using SAS 9.2 and ACCESS 2010 on Windows XP. I'll probably be upgrading to Windows 7 and SAS 9.4 soon so I can have integrated connectivity between ACCESS and SAS. Anyone knows if it solves those problems?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay folks, i found the answer, and its really simple.
Instead of exporting to a CSV file and then to Access, there is an option of exporting data directly from SAS to an Access database (somehow I missed it before...).
Seems to work well. It keeps the Hebrew characters and doesn't mess the data. The SAS table and the ACCESS table are not linked, but that's not an issue in my current application.

Code used:
`

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=lib.table
OUTTABLE= "table1"
DBMS=ACCESS REPLACE;
DATABASE= "L:\test.accdb";
RUN;
```

`

Comment: Please add the code you used to your answer (there are different ways to do this).

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for reminding me. I added the code to the answer.